# momentJS's toDate() returns invalid Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting in following format from PHP:

```
"end_date":{"date":"2017-02-17 18:52:31.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}]
```

at JS/AngularJS end I am doing following:

```
var end_date = Lease.period_ferme[idx].end_date
$scope.frame[idx].end_date = moment(end_date).toDate()
console.log('After');
console.log($scope.frame[idx].end_date); //invalid date
```

Comment: moment("2017-02-17 18:52:31.000000").toDate()
Fri Feb 17 2017 18:52:31 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) Looks correct to me.

Comment: Why this question deleted? Somone who don't know `momentJs` saying I used a wrong method?

Comment: Are you passing a whole object to moment() as an argument? maybe i didn't understant but shoudn't you use `moment(end_date.date)`?

Comment: @AurelianoFarSuau err Correct.

Answer (score 2):

if you [pass an Object to the Moment constructor](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/), that object should have fields named `year`, `month`, etc.  Your object does not, so Moment can't parse it and decides it's invalid.

As mentioned in the comment attached to your question, try creating a Moment object with just the date string:

`$scope.frame[idx].end_date = moment(end_date.date).toDate();`

or, since your JSON specifies UTC, try creating a Moment object using [`Moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

`$scope.frame[idx].end_date = moment.utc(end_date.date).toDate();`